# Extra info at the start of a sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence, clauses, sentence-patterns

Can someone tell me what the bolded parts are called in the following?

> **Starting in April**, Bob decided to drink 2 liters of water a day.
> **During the pandemic**, Joe got bored.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example is referred to as a *Participle Phrase*, I've found a fairly simple explanation [here](https://www.grammaring.com/participle-clauses).  The most pertinent part of the linked article to your specific question seems to be this explanation:

> a reason for the action in the main clause:
>
> - Having nothing left to do, Paula went home. (Since Paula had nothing left to do, she went home.)
> - Knowing a little Russian, I had no difficulty making myself understood. (As I knew a little Russian, I had no difficulty making myself understood.)
> - Working as a sales rep, I get to travel a lot. (I travel a lot because I work as a sales rep.)

Your second example is an instance of a *Prepositional Phrase*.  Since [during](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/during) is not a verb which has been modified, but is a preposition defining a point in the course of time.

[This article](https://www.theclassroom.com/difference-between-nominative-objective-pronouns-4968.html) does an alright job explaining the difference between the two.

Comment: No, _during_ is not a participle.

Comment: @JohnLawler, thanks for the clarification.  I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Those are **adverbial phrases**.

> In linguistics, an adverbial phrase is a multi-word expression operating adverbially: its syntactic function is to modify other expressions, including verbs, adjectives, adverbs, adverbials, and sentences.
>
> *Example*
> Next year, I will go on the cruise.
>
> — [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_phrase)

In this case, the phrases are modifying verbs. You can confirm they are adverbials by asking "[the adverb questions](https://www.english-grammar-revolution.com/adverb-questions.html)":

| Sentence | Question | Answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Starting in April, Bob decided to drink 2 liters of water a day. | How? | Starting in April. |
| During the pandemic, Joe got bored. | When? | During the pandemic. |

Particularly, an [adverbial](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial) at the start of the sentence is called a [fronted adverbial](https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/topics/zwwp8mn/articles/zp937p3).

> I will lose weight *next year*.
> *Next year*, I will lose weight.